# Install Qt Symbian build targets on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, symbian

I want to install Qt SDK for Symbian on my home computer, which runs Ubuntu Linux. I have already installed Qt Creator from the repos, but it doesn't have the Symbian environment. If possible, I don't want a duplicate Qt Creator installed in /opt, because I already have the one from the repos. Just the Symbian build targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the Symbian build targets aren't available by themselves from the Ubuntu repos.  The full [Nokia Qt SDK from Forum Nokia](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/e920da1a-5b18-42df-82c3-907413e525fb/Nokia_Qt_SDK.html) will do the job, but if you're not working on anything too critical, you could check out the [Qt SDK 1.1 Technology Preview](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/da8df288-e615-443d-be5c-00c8a72435f8/Qt_SDK.html), which comes with the Qt Mobility 1.1 APIs, has better QtQuick support etc, and doesn't integrate with existing Qt SDK installations.  In either case it might be an idea to uninstall the repo version of Qt Creator, otherwise you'll have two identical icons in your Applications menu.

Comment: I just want to write some Hello Word apps, nothing important. If I uninstall the repo Qt Creator I lose the Linux build targets, which I also want. Anyway, thanks for the link. I had previously installed the SDK successfully, but was wondering if there is a way to skip the duplicate Qt Creator. I'll try to install it again when I get back home.

Comment: The Nokia Qt SDK for Linux should include the Linux build targets, and also have the Simulator as a target.  If it doesn't apt-get installing libqt4-dev should take care of it.

Comment: I downloaded the offline Qt SDK (Linux 64-bit). It had checkboxes for which components I want to install, but ironically Qt Creator was the only checkbox that can't be unchecked.